# Azure hybrid connection to RabbitMQ Linux box

Tags: azure, connection-string, hybrid

Hi this is a basic question. I have an azure hybrid connection on a Windows Server on an on premise network. Does the local resource have to be the machine which the listener is installed on? For example

Hostname - RABBITLNX which runs the Rabbit Queue
Hostname - WINSRV which runs the hybrid listener

If I use RABBITLNX as the hostname for the resource when configuring the connection in Azure will that send it to the Rabbit machine?

Cheers, Chris.